# Uncountable nonstandard models of PA

Tags: set-theory, nonstandard-analysis, theories-of-arithmetic

Standard techniques (no pun intended) can be used to show that countable nonstandard models of Peano Arithmetic are order isomorphic to $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Z} \cdot \mathbb{Q}$.  Once we have used the compactness theorem to verify that nonstandard models of PA exist, we can appeal to the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem to ensure that we have countable ones.  We can then verify that these models form unbounded dense linear orders of $\mathbb{Z}$ blocks beyond the standard portion and use a back and forth argument to confirm that the nonstandard parts must always be order isomorphic.

My questions concern the structure of uncountable nonstandard models of PA.  The Löwenheim–Skolem theorem can be used to show that we have nonstandard models of arbitrarily large cardinality so:

(1) Is there an example of a set $M$ of the form $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{Z} \cdot D$ where $D$ is a dense linear order such that $M$ is *not* a model of PA?

(2) Can we find arbitrarily large $\kappa$ and nonstandard models of PA of size $\kappa$ such that there will be <strike>a</strike> **an unbounded** well-orderable subset of size $\kappa$ respecting the ordering relation of the nonstandard model (i.e. an order isomorphism between an ordinal and a subset of the model)?

(3) If the answer to (2) is no, what types of related results can we get?

Comment: @Jason: First, a brief comment: In (1) you probably mean: "Is there an unbounded dense linear order set $D$ such that there is no model of PA whose underlying order is isomorphic to N+ZD?"
Second, Shelah recently posted a nice (long) paper on the arXiv on questions of precisely this kind. You may find useful looking at it and at some of its references, http://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3342 From the abstract: "We hope to see how much for a model M of some completion T of PA (Peano Arithmetic) does M restriction {<} determine M, say up to isomorphism." (This is [Sh:924])

Comment: +1: @Andres: This is useful.  Thank you.

Comment: A trivial answer to Q1: Yes, for example $D=\mathbb Q + \mathbb R$. In M = N + Z*D there are countably infinite intervals [a,b], and there are elements c such that all [c,d] are uncountable.   Now let d:= c + (b-a), then the intervals [a,b] and [c,d] should be order isomorphic. 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Question 2 is an immediate consequence of the compactness theorem. Let $\kappa$ be fixed, and for each $\alpha < \kappa$ add a constant symbol $c_\alpha$ to the language. Add axioms of the form $c_\alpha < c_\beta$ for every $\alpha < \beta < \kappa$. The new theory $T$ is finitely satisfiable (every finite fragment is interpretable in the standard model of PA). So $T$ it is satisfiable, and the map $\alpha \mapsto c_\alpha$ is the desired embedding.

For question 1, it is known that $D$ cannot have the order type of the reals.  There is a nice survey by Bovykin and Kaye [1] that includes this fact and has a lot more information about order types of models of PA.  In the comments below, Andrey Bovykin suggests downloading his thesis from his homepage [2]; the paper is a summary of parts of the thesis.

1: Bovykin, Andrey; Kaye, Richard. *Order-types of models of Peano arithmetic.* (2002) Logic and algebra, 275--285, Contemp. Math., 302; [MR1928396](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1928396), [DOI: 10.1090/conm/302/05055](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/302/05055), http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maaib/orders.ps

2: https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~andrey/research.html

Comment: About Question 2: In fact, using compactness, *any* order can be a suborder of the ordering of a model of PA. There are more general results here; for example, the Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski theorem.

Comment: @Carl: +1: Thanks for the answer and link.

What I really wanted to ask for Question 2 was whether we could get a well order of size $\kappa$ that's unbounded in the nonstandard model.  Is this possible?

Comment: Jason, Carl's $c_{\alpha}$'s are that desired subset.  They satisfy the axioms $c_{\alpha} < c_{\beta}$ for $\alpha < \beta < \kappa$, and that's precisely what it means for $\alpha \mapsto c_{\alpha}$ to be an order isomorphism.

Comment: Amit, the constants may not be unbounded in the constructed nonstandard model.  For example, consider the introduction of only one constant $c$.  Then the nonstandard model would also have the successor of whatever the interpretation of $c$ were.

Comment: Hmmm... what if we add to $T$ formulas that say: $\forall p_0 \dots \forall p_n [(p_1 < c_{\alpha} \wedge \dots \wedge p_n < c_{\alpha} \wedge \exists x \phi (x, p_1, \dots , p_n)) \rightarrow \exists x < c_{\beta} \phi (x, p_1, \dots , p_n)]$ for each $\alpha < \beta$ and $\phi$ a formula with n+1 free variables.  Obtain a model using compactness, and then look at the cut of the model in which the $c_{\alpha}$ are unbounded.  This cut will model $PA$, in fact it will be an elementary substructure since, by the formulas we added to $T$, the Tarski-Vaught criterion will be met.

Comment: The formula in my last comment is just saying that if $\alpha < \beta$ and some existential statement involving parameters below $c_{\alpha}$ is true, then it has a witness below $c_{\beta}$.

Comment: Alternatively, to get a model of PA with a cofinal sequence of length $\kappa$, note first that, by compactness, any model of PA has an elementary extension containing a new element above all the old ones.  Now iterate this for $\kappa$ steps (taking unions at limit stages).

Comment: @Andreas: I may be overlooking something well known, but when you take the union, how do you know it is a model of PA?  It seems like that fact would imply PA has a $\Pi^0_2$ axiomatization. 

Comment: @Amit, @Andreas: +1, Thanks.  These are both great answers.
@Carl: Andreas is forming an elementary chain of models of PA and then using the fact that the union of them will be a model such that all of the ones constructed below are elementary substructures.  I don't think that he is claiming that the union of an arbitrary collection of models of PA is a model of PA; this certainly is not the case for ZFC.   Also, thanks again for your answer and reference.  Both are helpful.

Comment: @Carl: Andreas is taking a union of a chain of *elementary* extensions, not just of elementarily equivalent models.

Comment: @Carl: I'm thinking of this construction as forming a directed system of embeddings and taking the direct limit of the system of embeddings at limit stages.

Comment: Thanks Jason and Andres. I was assuming it was something obvious like that, just a mental block. 

Comment: If you have a chain of elementary extensions, then their union is an elementary extension of them all by the Tarski-Vaught criterion.

Comment: Instead of downloading my paper with Kaye that is a survey of some parts of my PhD thesis, it is better to download the actual PhD thesis (written 11 years ago) from 
http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~andrey/research.html

As far as I know, nothing new about order-types of models of arithmetic has been proved since then.

(Well, there is another article of mine "Resplendent models and definability with an oracle" but this is about a connection between the order-type of models of arithmetic and linear orders that are interpreted in that model, so not exactly relevant to your question).

Comment: The link http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maaib/orders.ps in your answer no longer works. I guess it might have benn link to the paper Andrey Bovykin and *Richard Kaye Order-types of models of Peano arithmetic: a short survey*...? This paper is mentioned among references in the Wikipedia article [Non-standard model of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic).

Comment: @Carl Mummer I have edited the post to include the full bibliographic details (so that others do not have to track this down just based on the link which seems to be dead). I hope this is the paper you had mind. It seems that similar survey is [freely available](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/publ/papers/survey6.pdf) on website of one of the authors. This survey and the PhD theosis mentioned above are given as references in [the current revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic&oldid=786524066#References) of the Wikipedia article.

Comment: the link to my PhD works, and always worked. Sorry for the delay --- I just noticed you needed it.
https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~andrey/phd.pdf